# Update git-svn git mirror without redownloading everything

Tags: git, svn, version-control, github, git-svn

I made a git mirror of a svn repository using

```
    git svn clone svn://svn.svnrepo.com
```

I uploaded it to github and was able to update the local repo using

```
    git svn rebase svn://svn.svnrepo.com
```

and push the updates to github

Later after I had deleted the local copy I wanted to update the remote again

So I cloned the git repo

```
    git clone git://git.gitrepo.com
```

But when I tried to rebase I got an error

```
    git svn rebase svn://svn.svnrepo.com

    Data from a previous version of git-svn exists, but

    (required for this version (1.8.3.2) of git-svn) does not exist.

    Done migrating from a git-svn v1 layout
```

then it gives an Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history error

Ive tried:

```
    git svn init svn://svn.svnrepo.com
```

with:

```
    git svn fetch
```

but that starts a re-download of the entire svn repo which takes over 24 hours
The current svn revision is marked by the git-svn-id in the commit log and seems fine, how do I stop git svn fetch from re-fetching files that already exist or rebase it without an entire re-download? This mirror never had commits that would make it different from the svn upstream.

Comment: Could you please add some more readability to your question.

Comment: Fixed, messed up the formatting initially

Comment: Not sure I understand the solution. I am also receiving this error. Could you update with what you did for the solution?

Comment: I haven't found a solution to this problem yet.

Answer (score 2):

just need to run the following commands

```
git config svn-remote.svn.url $SVN_URL
git config svn-remote.svn.fetch :refs/remotes/git-svn
svn2git --rebase
```

or you can also manually edit `.git/config` to add the `svn-remote` section:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = SVN_URL
    fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn
```

and from now on just `svn2git --rebase`

--

PS: credit to my sources:

- http://blog.tfnico.com/2010/08/syncing-your-git-repo-with-subversion.html
- [How can I reconnect a git repository with a svn repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954644/how-can-i-reconnect-a-git-repository-with-a-svn-repository?#13105418)

Comment: PS: if you wanna retry from scratch remember to drop the `.git/svn/` directory