# git svn gives 500 internal server error

Tags: git, svn

We are trying migration from svn to git. When I try to do `git svn clone`, we are getting below exception.

```
Can't create session: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 
'https://myhost.com/svn/repos/sampleRepo/testProject': Unexpected server 
error 500 'Internal Server Error' on '/svn/repos/sampleRepo/testProject' 
at /mingw64/share/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN.pm line 143.
```

But when we try `svn checkout`, repository got checked out fine. What could be the reason?

**UPDATE**

Worked fine with Cygwin. But same exception with command prompt and Git Bash

Answer (score 0):

The [`SVN.pm` perl script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/perl/Git/SVN.pm#L142) mentions:

```
my $url = $remote->{url} or die "svn-remote.$repo_id.url not defined\n";
```

Double-check the value of `git config svn-remote.svn.url`

See more at "[How can I reconnect a git repository with a svn repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13105418/6309)".

Comment: Verified the url. It is valid.

Comment: @Sangeeth Still the perl script seems to error on that line. What version of git are you using?

Comment: git version 2.8.1.windows.1. It worked fine with cygwin.

Comment: @Sangeeth Also, can you try it in a regular CMD session instead of a git bash session?